# Merge function error - On Clause cannot be updated - PK issue

Tags: oracle

Procedure is to check the the eid ,and do merge. While updating the existing row, it needs to update with the eid.seq.nextval.
I have created a the sequence and calling in Procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Temp(
Eid Number,
dpt varchar2
) As
BEGIN

    MERGE INTO Src1 e
        USING (select v_eid as eid
            , v_dept as dept
              FROM dual) d
         ON (e.eid = d.eid)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (e.eid,e.dept)
                VALUES(d.eid, d.dept)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET e.eid = eid_SEQ.nextval, e.dept = d.dept;

   END;
/
```

Error:

```
1.ORA--38104:ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated.
```

IF I remove the ON clause condition then PK cannot be null error .

Also, the best procedure to call the seq.nextval in the procedure.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to update `eid`, but if you must you can do a `SELECT` to see if there is a match then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` accordingly.

Comment: If the record matches on `eid`, and your update then changes the value of `eid`, then the record no longer matches. It makes sense that Oracle doesn't allow you to do this with a Merge.

Comment: I agree to the point, but my requirement is, the eid is Unique ID and when the input parameter has the matching value then,that row has to be updated with other Paramater values and a new Primary key to be created(type 2 dimension). If the value is new, then new (sequence.nextval) will have to be inserted as new row.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is impossible with a merge statement. Think about it: you're trying to update the value of a field that is used to determine if the field should be updated. This is not safe, especially if the merge statement updates/inserts more than one row.

Apart from that it is close to impossible to suggest an alternative since `eid` seems to be a primary key and updating primary keys is normally a bad thing.

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't be possible in principle. The row to be updated could be "tagged" and the update done in a second step. Seems more like an implementation detail leaked as an error...